# Override vendor model in laravel 6.X

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to override the model inside of vendor. I tried bellow code. But not working.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind('VendorName\Models\User', 'App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Extending model is not an option, as i have to override all controller change model path and write all methods again, its not worth it.

Comment: did you try to simpy extend the vendor model or is this not enough?

Comment: No i want to override. I can override the controllers but not models.

Answer (score 0):

Binding a class in the container like this isn't going to override direct references to the class you're trying to override if the object isn't being resolved using the service container.

So for example, something like `$user = new \VendorName\Models\User;` isn't going to be affected because it's simply not using the container.

I think the only sensible solution is to refactor your code so you're using a class that extends the base `User` class.

Comment: Does the package have a config that specifies which user model to use?

Comment: There is no option in config to define model path.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more details, like what package you're using and more details on your use case.